# How can I change the keyboard shortcut for switching the active window?

Tags: front-end, customization, keyboard, windows

The default keyboard shortcut (on Windows at least) for switching focus to the next window is Ctrl+F6, and for switching to the previous windows it's Shift+Ctrl+F6.  How can I change this to Ctrl+Tab and Shift+Ctrl+Tab respectively (or some other pair of combinations which is not used by default)?

Comment: You'll want to see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405)...

Comment: @J.M. this command doesn't appear to be in `KeyEventTranslations.tr` -- interesting.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: it's definitely not in Linux (that's why I couldn't post an answer); have you checked Windows by any chance?

Comment: @J.M. yes, I am on Windows 7 and at least the command is not obvious if it is there; searching for "F6" reveals nothing.

Comment: This [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/de773c23a86dc065/8b8d086dffb85d5f) on Mathgroup might be of use here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add the following to `KeyEventTranslations.tr`:

```
Item[KeyEvent["Tab", Modifiers -> {Control}],
   FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["CycleNotebooksForward"]]],

Item[KeyEvent["Tab", Modifiers -> {Shift, Control}],
   FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["CycleNotebooksBackward"]]],
```

This will map <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycling between notebooks.

For some reason, using the Tab key sometimes fails, but any alternative shortcut could be used (for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd>).

On Windows `KeyEventTranslation.tr` is located in

```
$InstallationDirectory\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows
```

Comment: For example, ``Item[KeyEvent["`", Modifiers -> {Control}],  FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["CycleNotebooksForward"]]],`` works, too.

Comment: Perhaps Ctrl+Tab fails sometimes because it is already mapped?

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work when I want to switch away from a minimized window.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> are default Windows keyboard shortcuts, although I was only aware of the Tab variants.

Because of this, these commands on not (apparently) configurable from within *Mathematica*.  Further, *Mathematica* does not recognize the Tab commands.

---

It may be possible to rig something using `SetSelectedNotebook` but so far I have failed to do this within the the confines of `KeyEventTranslations.tr` and `MenuSetup.tr`.  Perhaps an `EventHandler` within a Palette could be made to work but I am tired of this problem.

Comment: Aha -- they're Windows's, not Mathematica's.

Comment: FWIW, on a Mac it's CMD + `, and this does work within Mathematica by default.