# tol and None in output of CompilePrint

Tags: compile

**A bit of background:**

I'm trying to fit a very complicated symbolic function. By compiling the function I got about 100x speedup, but I would need another 10. Therefore I'm trying to understand if the function is correctly compiled (I allready checked that there are no calls to MainEvaluate).

**The problem:**

While scanning through the output of `CompilePrint` I see the following snippet repeating a lot

```
12  B0 = R39 None R38 (tol R42)
13  if[ !B0] goto 46
```

**The question:**

What does line **12** do? Is this R39 * **None** * R38? What is (**tol** R42)?

Here is some more context:

```
    33 arguments
    1 Boolean register
    1 Integer register
    123 Real registers
    Underflow checking off
    Overflow checking off
    Integer overflow checking off
    RuntimeAttributes -> {}

    R0 = A1
    R1 = A2
            ...
    Result = R64

1   R38 = Reciprocal[ R2]
2   R39 = R37 * R38
3   R38 = R36 + R39
4   R39 = Reciprocal[ R38]
5   R38 = - R39
6   R39 = - R2
7   R41 = R40 + R39
8   R39 = Reciprocal[ R2]
9   R41 = R41 * R39
10  R39 = R36 + R38 + R41
11  R38 = I0
12  B0 = R39 None R38 (tol R42)
13  if[ !B0] goto 46
....
19k something lines:)
```

Comment: Can you try to come up with a much smaller function that produces a similar output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without seeing the code that generated the above this is only a guess. If you look in:

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns", "Applications", 
  "CompiledFunctionTools", "PrintCode.m"}]
```

you'll find a line:

```
toInfixForm[_] := None
```

All infix form conversions not known (i.e. in that list in that file) are replaced by `None`.

It would be good to find out which expr is not mentioned in the `toInfixForm` such that it can be added. Presumably this is some compare function. In that same file you will also find **tol**.

Comment: The missing operations are (at least): Unequal, Greater, GreaterEqual. Is it safe just to add them to the file?

Comment: @Ajasja, yes, I'd think that adding this is safe. You could make a backup of the modified file, just in case you want to go back to it later.

Comment: +1. Everything appears to be working correctly. None was in fact ">=" (in my case) .

Comment: @Ajasja I'm wondering if the license permits modifying that file and sharing it publicly.  In any case, sharing just a patch (the diff) is probably safe.

Comment: Maybe the question should be tagged [bug], then?

Comment: @celtschk I'd consider this a missing feature rather than a bug (such as a valid looking but incorrect result).  I described here in a bit more detail why I thought a [bug] tag was a good idea: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/355/12

Comment: @Szabolcs Actually the licence prohibits any sort of modification even if you don't distribute the result. However, practically speaking, we probably have to apply some common sense when interpreting the ridiculously strict *Mathematica* licence agreement. For example, some countries have provisions in their copyright law that would allow modifications if they're to correct problems in the original code, which would render that clause invalid (for copyright purposes, at least).

Comment: @OleksandrR. You're right, I just found "c. modifying the Software in any manner, except those portions written in the Mathematica language and included as examples".  It also has "b. decompiling, disassembling, or reverse engineering the Software".  That's a surprise given the culture of reverse engineering or "spelunking" the Mathematica community has.  There's even a doc page titles "Low-Level System Spelunking".

Comment: I would also tag this as a bug. I spent quite some time going through the uncompiled expression in order to figure out from where a `None` symbol was coming from.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ahh, but then this should also apply to files like [`KeyEventTranslation.tr`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/how-can-i-change-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-switching-the-active-window), but nobody was raising the point there:)

Answer (score 7):

`None` stands for an operation for which Wolfram has forgotten to implement a specific name in output, and `tol` probably stands for "tolerance". For example, see

```
CompilePrint[Compile[{a,b},a!=b]]
(*
==> 
            1 Boolean register
            3 Real registers
            Underflow checking off
            Overflow checking off
            Integer overflow checking on
            RuntimeAttributes -> {}

            R0 = A1
            R1 = A2
            R2 = 7.
            Result = B0

    1   B0 = R0 None R1 (tol R2)
    2   Return
*)
```

Note that you get the same result when using `>` instead of `!=`. Unfortunately that means that the information in the decompiled code is incomplete.

Comment: +1. Well it's not that obvious, especially as it reminds of the symbol `None`:)

Comment: @celtschk, as I have shown above, None is inserted for any symbol that is not mentioned in the `toInfixForm` It could be other things than !=

Comment: @Ajasja: I didn't mean "obviously" as "it should be obvious to you" but as "it seems obvious to *me*" (i.e. it's not something I know from any source, so there's still a small chance that I'm wrong).

Comment: Interesting: `CompilePrint[Compile[{a, b}, a > b]]` produces "None" while `CompilePrint[Compile[{a, b}, a < b]]` produces "<"

Comment: I see, so my conclusion was indeed wrong. I'll update my answer to reflect my new knowledge.

Comment: @Ajasja Infact "!=" and ">" produce the same code ...

Comment: @belisarius I think the code is correct, just the display is wrong

Comment: @belisarius: No, they do not produce the same code, as you can see by looking at the `FullForm`: At one position, `!=` produces an `8` while `>` produces a `7`. Only the disassembly looks the same.

Comment: @celtschk Sorry, I was trying to say that.