# DisplayFormula not working as expected

Tags: output-formatting, stylesheet

How do I use the styles `"DisplayFormula"` and `"DisplayFormulaNumbered"`?

Why is there no margin (or empty space) around the formula?
Why does the latter **not** display numbers?

How to set those styles to do what one expects?

Comment: I agree that there is no extra margin on the left, but when using `DisplayFormulaNumbered` I get a number on the extreme right side. What exactly do you expect?

Comment: I do not get a number on the right side. I expect a certain margin, offsetting the formula from the plain text. The problem arises - as I now realize - from the cell being inline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a walk-through with some of the shortcuts that I like to use.

Normally, you'd enter text and inline formulas using the cell style `"Text"`, and when you're ready to enter a displayed equation you have to start a new cell. 
At that point, you would go to the menu and select, e.g., the style `"DisplayFormulaNumbered"` with the mouse. Having to take your hands off the keyboard for this purpose inevitably slows you down. But this can be avoided if you make use of the <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> shortcut for `Format > Style > Other...`: 
[image: Other...]

At this point, I select `DisplayFormulaNumbered`, and this selection will be remembered next time you do <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> to insert further displayed equations, so you can dismiss the dialog without using the mouse by pressing <kbd>Return</kbd>. It's even remembered across *Mathematica* sessions. This is the fastest way to get into the `DisplayFormulaNumbered` environment in a new cell.

Usually I now enter the equation in `TraditionalForm`. The default format type for displayed equations is not `TraditionalForm`, but you get that format either by converting an existing inline equation to `DisplayFormulaNumbered` (as mentioned by the OP), or by pasting a `TraditionalForm` expression, or by doing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> on whatever you type in the new `DisplayFormulaNumbered` cell.

Another useful trick for numbered equations is the shortcut for entering equation references described in [Albert Retey's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6586/245) to "Creating a cross referencing shortcut."

If you now want to change the margins or alignment of the `DisplayFormulaNumbered` cell, that can be done by selecting `Format > Edit Stylesheet...` and choosing the style `DisplayFormulaNumbered` from the popup menu. Then you can highlight the template cell that appears, and change (e.g.) `Format > Text Alignment > Align Center`.

Comment: This is a little off topic, but what is the purpose of using DisplayFormula. What is the advantage of this over using an Inline cell within a Text cell. Similarly, what is the advantage of using the style InlineFormula?

Comment: @BenAllgeier I'm proposing to use `DisplayFormulaNumbered` because it provides equation numbers that can be referenced later. The difference between displayed and inline formulas becomes clear when you use symbols requiring two-dimensional typesetting, e.g., sums and integrals with limits. Inline formulas don't typeset the limits below and above the symbol, but next to it (by default).

Comment: Thanks. I thought perhaps they had something to do with LaTeX. I have `ScriptLevel->0` for `InlineCell` so I guess I forgot that issue. It seems more difficult to type in formulas in `DisplayFormula` than it does in a `Text` cell (if you don't want Equation Numbers). Are you supposed to use `InlineFormula` inside of a text cell like you do `Inline Cell` (those two sound the same but I can only see use for `InlineCell`).

Answer (score 3):

You must NOT use inline math cells. A `DisplayFormula` must be a cell on its own. If you want to turn an inline math cell into a `DisplayFormula`, first select the line containing it and choose "Divide Cells", then apply the `DisplayFormula` style to the new cell!