# Shortcut Ctrl+Shift+8

Tags: front-end, keyboard

What does the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> does in *Mathematica* (version 10)? On Windows 8.1 it displays a little square:

[image]

I can write in it, but I don't understand what it does.

Comment: does nothing apparent on windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is supporting another visual form of typing code into mathmatica.
Just have a look under Menu - Palettes - Basic Math Assistant. There you can figure out some of them.

Comment: It looks like it is a way to insert text that won't be treated as a mathematical equation.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 verry helpfull Topics on Help;

[Keyboard Shortcut Listing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html#604640720)

with some more links on the verry end of the page

> See "Letters and Letter-like Forms", "Operators", "Notational Alphabet Characters", and "Special Characters" for more information on the Wolfram Language's special characters.

[Notebook Shortcuts](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NotebookShortcuts.html)

> The Wolfram System's interface is carefully optimized for both menu
>   and keyboard use—with many convenient ergonomic features, including
>   some that are not immediately visible from menus.

[Special Characters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SpecialCharacters.html)

> The Wolfram Language not only has systemwide support for arbitrary Unicode characters, but also includes nearly a thousand carefully designed characters for mathematical notation and technical presentation—all fully integrated into the Wolfram Language's input, output, and graphics.

On 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014) this looks like

`\[EmptySquare]` or `\[Square]`

see [EmptySquare](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/EmptySquare.html) and [Square](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Square.html)

It also has precisely on this forum a lot of good information on the topic "custom shortcut" see [How can I change the keyboard shortcut for switching the active window?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/how-can-i-change-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-switching-the-active-window), this may also be an indication for further search.