# How do I query all the Mathematica keystroke mappings?

Tags: front-end, mac-os-x

In https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html the keystroke control-F6 key combination is listed as way to cycle between active Mathematica windows.
None of these documented options work on MacOS.  I tried all the mac keyboard specific F6 related variations like fn-F6, option-F6, command-F6 with no luck, and eventually the magic combination is nothing F6 related, but is command+` (ref: comment by TransferOrbit in: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1951/10).

Given that the documentation above appears to be Windows specific, is there a way to systematically display all the active Mathematica keystroke mappings, so that I could see what they are independent of the operating system that I happen to be using?